# Is the Lebesgue measure of A zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A=:\{(x,x)|x\in[0,1]\}\subset[0,1]\times[0,1]$
I am trying to figure out why is $m(A)=0$ ?

I have proven so far that it is closed and thus it is a Borel set, hence it is measurable. It is also uncountable. 
Any valuable hints?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $n$ be a positive integer.  Cover the diagonal with $n$ squares whose sides have length $\frac{1}{n}$.